# How to handle left padding/margin when using Container-Fluid in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, asp.net-mvc-5

I am a beginner in web development and I am stuck at one place in my ASP.Net MVC 5 Project.

In modern web sites, mostly, **Container-Fluid** is used to utilize full width of the browser when viewing homepage. But problem is now even when I go to Register form, there is no padding to the left. Basically, I wanted fluid for homepage, but when I go to register or even login page, I expect some padding.

My Layout File:

```
<div class="container-fluid body-content">
        @RenderBody()
</div>
```

Register Page View:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
    {
        <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LastName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>     
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Register" />
        </div>
    </div>        
    }
```

P.S: I can harcode some padding, but since I am not very good with Responsive Web Design so I wanted to use **inbuilt Twitter Classes**. Can some one guide me on how to handle this scenario.

1. `Register` text is completely touching the browser left panel.
2. When I squeeze the browser then All the form field touches the browser panel.

[image]

[image]

Html Generated:

```
<div class="container-fluid body-content">
<h2>Register.</h2>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="FirstName">FirstName</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The FirstName field is required." id="FirstName" name="FirstName" type="text" value="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="LastName">LastName</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The LastName field is required." id="LastName" name="LastName" type="text" value="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="Password">Password</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Register">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> Please guide me how to handle this in a graceful way. Because I will
>   face this left padding problem in all the pages.

Comment: use container for other pages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use the bootstrap grid correctly you should be using the proper classes from https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid

This should result in code like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      @RenderBody()
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It looks like you are missing a div with the `row` class. Also you are missing some form elements (such as `<form class="form-horizontal">`). Check https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#forms-horizontal

You should not mix classes with with `container-fluid` like you have done with `container-fluid body-content`, especially when your additional classes (`body-content`) have padding or margin styles. This is because bootstrap uses `container`, `container-fluid`, `row` and `col-x-x` to provide correct margins and padding (`container-fluid` should give you a 15px padding by default).

You can use your browsers dev tools to inspect the different divs to see what styles are being applied by which classes. It may also be worth checking to see if any other styles are overriding bootstrap.

Comment: Thank you so much for detailed explanation. Point 1: I have `form-horizontal`l embeded in my form. sorry that I pasted incomplete snippet. Point 2: When you say do not use `body-content`, but I did not add it, it was there along with `container` class. So do you want me to delete `body-content` when I am using `container-fluid`?

Comment: Also, unless I am missing something. I have not removed `row `or any `col-sm-12` class from my Standard template just before the `RenderBody`. I have not touched that part of code. It's the standard template that got generated from ASP.Net MVC 5 Web application.

Comment: I am not sure, why would ASP.Net MVC 5 template would do such a blunder.

Comment: If you see my "Register View Page" section and check the first line of code, it has "Form-Horizontal" class.. :)

Comment: Also, there is no other class in play. I just created a basic solution and I hardly have added any class. I just changed the container to container-fluid.

Comment: Sir, I explicitly added the `row` and then added the `offset and col` to make everything central. Its working fine now. I still wonder how come we don't have `class="ROW"` by default in tempalte that is getting created in ASP.Net MVC

Answer (score 1):

If you generated your project from a template there is this selector in `Site.css`. You may have removed it but you can add it back in.

```
/* Set padding to keep content from hitting the edges */
.body-content {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I had removed it. Added it back. :)